# Unable to Rewrite directory with fullstop in name to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I need to rewrite a directory and all is contents to a new directory however I am having issues I think due to the source directory having a full stop in it.

i.e.

http://example.com/1.0/ to http://example.com/newfolder/

Here is the rule I am trying

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^1\.0$ http://example.com/newfolder/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^1\.0(/.*)?$ http://example.com/newfolder$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `/1.0/anything` to `/newfolder/anything`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, when I try that it still does not work but if I try RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ http://example.com/newfolder$1 [R=301,L] that works, its seems to not like the folder starting with a number?

Comment: No it is fine. Does `/1.0/` have another .htaccess?

Comment: Great that worked there was just a blank one in that folder which i have now renamed, do you know why the rule seems to drop any post variables being sent across?

Comment: If there is any .htaccess in any sub directory then parent's directives are all ignores. This is default Apache functionality. You can add `RewriteOptions Inherited` to inherit parent's directives.